# Loop when "talking to machine"

Tags: java, loops, case, java.util.scanner

I want it to look as if the users input is being responded to by the machine in a loop like sequence that goes back to the original question and allows the previous answers to be accepted as viable answers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
    String text = input.nextLine();

    switch (text) {
    case "start":
        System.out.println("Machine Started!");
        break;

    case "stop":
        System.out.println("Machine Stopped.");
        break;

    case "sleep":
        System.out.println("In progress: sleeping...");
        break;

    case "transform":
        System.out.println("In progress: transforming...");
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Command not recognized");
    }       
}
}
```

Comment: Just put all the code after instantiating the `Scanner` into a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
    String text;

    do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
    text = input.nextLine();

    switch (text) {
    case "start":
        System.out.println("Machine Started!");
        break;

    case "stop":
        System.out.println("Machine Stopped.");
        break;

    case "sleep":
        System.out.println("In progress: sleeping...");
        break;

    case "transform":
        System.out.println("In progress: transforming...");
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Command not recognized");
    } 
    } while (!text.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));      
}
}
```

This should be what you are looking for. The program will abort when user types in quit